# debug an array of linked lists in c

Tags: arrays, c, linked-list

I'm having a trouble in my project, at first I made one linked list and it worked properly but then I had to edit it and make it an array of linked list, but it just stores in a wrong way I guess, here is my code,  what's wrong with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int coeff;
    int power;
    struct node* Next;
};

  
void Insert(int X,int Y, struct node* L, struct node* P)
{
    struct node* temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->coeff = X;
    temp->power = Y;
    temp->Next = P->Next;
    P->Next = temp;
}

   
void PrintList(struct node* L)
{
    struct node* P = L;
            printf("%d %d ",P->coeff,P->power);
            printf("\n");
             P=P->Next;
}


int main()
{

    struct node* head[3] ;
    for(int q =0 ; q!= 3 ; q++)
    {

        head[q] = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    }

   

        Insert(1,2,head[0],&head[0]);
        Insert(2,3,head[0],&head[0]);
        Insert(1,2,head[1],&head[1]);
        Insert(2,2,head[1],&head[1]);

      
    

for(int i=0 ;i!=3;i++){
        
PrintList(head[i]);

}



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a lot of warnings about incompatible argument types from this code. Always turn on all compiler warnings. BTW, what's the point of the 3rd argument in `Insert`? It isn't used at all.

Comment: `head[q] = malloc(sizeof(struct node));` head[q] is allocated, but not initialised. It can contain garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a LinkedList there is only 1 head. You have allocated 3 different heads and are trying to add nodes to these heads. So the following answer *assumes* you intend to have 3 different LinkedLists with each list's head in an array.

The memory from `malloc()` in this line

```
head[q] = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

was uninitialized. Using [`calloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) appeared more prudent here. So,

```
head[q] = calloc(sizeof(struct node), 1); //Initialize everything to 0
```

Next, one of the arguments in your `Insert()` was redundant and also didn't go with your calling code. It is of the signature

```
void Insert(int ,int , struct node* , struct node*)
```

but you're invoking it with

```
void Insert(int ,int , struct node* , struct node**)
```

Dropping the last argument should be fine, I guess, in this case since you aren't modifying the incoming `struct node*` pointer but its contents instead. In case you were changing the `struct node*` to point to something else within the `Insert()` function (e.g. `P = temp;` etc.), then passing in a `struct node**` would have more meaning. So, changing your code to

```
void Insert(int X,int Y, struct node* P)
{
    struct node* temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->coeff = X;
    temp->power = Y;
    temp->Next = P->Next;
    P->Next = temp;
}
```

And the calling code to

```
Insert(2,3,head[0]);
Insert(1,2,head[0]);
Insert(1,2,head[1]);
Insert(2,2,head[1]);
```

Next, changing your `PrintList` to actually traverse the LinkedList:

```
void PrintList(struct node* L)
{
    struct node* P = L;
    while(P) {
        printf("%d %d\n",P->coeff,P->power);
        P=P->Next;
    }
}
```

Apart from that, I just added some logging to better clarify the LinkedList being printed.

```
for(int i=0 ;i!=3;i++){
    printf("Printing list %d:\n", i);
    PrintList(head[i]);
    printf("*****\n");
}
```

This gives the output:

```
Printing list 0:
0 0
1 2
2 3
*****
Printing list 1:
0 0
2 2
1 2
*****
Printing list 2:
0 0
*****
```

Obviously, all the `head` of the LinkedLists are 0 initialized and hence show up as `0 0`. They could be initialized as deemed fit, or could be dropped from the `PrintList()` function altogether, depending on your program's expectations.

Comment: How could you delete one node from the above list? Is it possible with a function again? For example, to delete the first set that entered a list when it has to be deleted?

Comment: @wajaap In this case, the first set that entered a list would be the last in the list, since the insertion is always adding nodes after the head. So you'd need to traverse the list and delete the last node. There's obviously no _built-in_ function to do that, you'd need to write that. Or you could always maintain a pointer to the end of the list and then just delete nodes from the end without traversing the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

When working on a C project you should always enable compiler warnings. If you do the compiler will issue a warning like

```
warning: passing argument 4 of ‘Insert’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

This is just the first problem in your code. You also have uninitialized fields in the nodes you allocate in the main function.

Instead of having a function which modifies the list, it is more flexible to define a function which adds a new node to a list and returns the new list. Below is an alternative approach which also uses convenience macro functions for allocating memory and calculating the length of an array. The code also hides the pointer behind a type definition and defines a function which frees a list.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN(array) ((int) (sizeof (array) / sizeof (array)[0]))

#define NEW_ARRAY(pointer, length) \
    { \
        (pointer) = malloc(((size_t) length) * sizeof (pointer)[0]); \
        if ((pointer) == NULL) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Allocating memory with malloc failed: %s\n", strerror(errno)); \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
        } \
    }

#define NEW(pointer) NEW_ARRAY((pointer), 1)

typedef struct node *List;

struct node {
    int coeff;
    int power;
    struct node *next;
};
    
List NewList(int coeff, int power, List next)
{
    List node;

    NEW(node);
    node->coeff = coeff;
    node->power = power;
    node->next = next;
    return node;
}


void FreeList(List list)
{
    if (list != NULL) {
        FreeList(list->next);
        free(list);
    }
}


void PrintList(List list)
{
    while (list != NULL) {
        printf("%d %d\n", list->coeff, list->power);
        list = list->next;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    List head[3] ;

    head[0] = NewList(1, 2, NewList(2, 3, NULL));
    head[1] = NewList(1, 2, NewList(2, 2, NULL));
    head[2] = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < LEN(head); i++) {
        PrintList(head[i]);
        FreeList(head[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```